# Images not changing on mobile devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I want the images im using as the background to change to smaller versions through css media queries.

I'm not quite sure why it is not working on mobile devices.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 667px) and (orientation : landscape){

#slide1 {
background: url(../images/slides/mobiletest.jpg) center center no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
width: 100%;}}
```

Comment: I would personally use PHP to identify browser type and then display a specific stylesheet for each. Maybe have on `global.css` with elements that would not change between browser format changes. Then have a `desktop.css` then `mobile.css`. You could also use jQuery/JavaScript. I do also believe that HTML5 now allows you to identify mobile devices. I would still go with the PHP alternative however.

Comment: Okay Ill take that approach most likely.

Comment: Do you know of any tools that allow me to view what my site looks likes on mobile devices via the browser. The tools I found aren't accurate when I check on actual mobile device.

Comment: You can try using Google chrome mobile simulator for the testing.

Comment: @AdamParish I am not sure exactly, and with so many different mobile devices it is hard to test each display. In addition, depending on your emphasis on CSS you may want to create PHP functions and some simple `if` statements to add different stylesheets per device. The PHP code may long run, but would allow quicker page loading with multiple, smaller stylesheets that are only called if needed instead of one big one.

Answer (score 0):

This could really be some specifity issue. You can try adding a html selector before the element:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 667px) and (orientation : landscape){

    html #slide1 {
        background: url(../images/slides/mobiletest.jpg) center center no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 667px) and (orientation : landscape){

    html #slide1 {
        background: url(../images/slides/mobiletest.jpg) center center no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: 100% 100% !important;
        -moz-background-size: cover !important;
        background-size: 100% 100% !important;
        background-attachment: fixed !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

use !important in css hope it can work