# Images not scalling down on actual mobile device

Tags: css, iphone, image-scaling

I am having a problem where my images don't scale down when they are on mobile.
I'm using images as a background layer on the site each with parallax effects.

If I look at the site using the chrome dev tools on an iphone 6 it scales them down but on the actual mobile device it does not.

I tried using media queries targeting an iphone 6 directly and also tried again with one that switches out the image to a smaller version.

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: is this still related to your old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687238/images-not-changing-on-mobile-devices ?

Comment: Sort of I thought I'd reword it since I didnt explain the problem as much on the last question.